# How to fix "updating crates.io index failed" problem when I build the Rust project

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I have a problem building the Rust project.
I have changed the Cargo.toml like the following:

```
[package]
name = "here"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
rand="0.8.5"
```

Only added rand to dependencies.
But, when I build the project, updating crates.io index took too long and the result was like the following:

```
E:\Workspace\rust\example>cargo build
Updating crates.io index
warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): failed to read data: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
; class=Os (2)
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): failed to read data: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
; class=Os (2)
error: failed to get rand as a dependency of package game1 v0.1.0 (C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Files\game1)

Caused by:
failed to load source for dependency rand

Caused by:
Unable to update registry https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index

Caused by:
failed to fetch https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index

Caused by:
failed to read data: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
; class=Os (2)
```

This is the full error message. What is this? How can I fix it?
Please, help me.

I tried like the following:(https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/9335)

```
[net]
git-fetch-with-cli = true
```

in C:\Users\my_name.cargo\config

But, the error is not resolved.
Help me.

I use windows 10 OS.

Comment: Not a full solution, but does using nightly `cargo +nightly -Zsparse-registry build` works for you?

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Is it the solution?

Comment: I would call it a workaround, if it works for you.

Comment: Well, I have installed stable version. Do i have to install nightly version?

Comment: To do that, yes.

Comment: Thank you, cafce25.
cargo +nightly -Zsparse-registry build
It works for me.

Comment: Sparse registry stabilized for 1.58.0!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Mr.Chayim, you are a very kind of person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full solution, but since Rust 1.58.0 you can use [sparse registry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/cargo/reference/registries.html#registry-protocols). In .cargo/config.toml, set `registries.crates-io.protocol` to `"sparse"`.